# Android Accessing textViews from a custom listView Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I cannot access the item's contents using the bellow code. Why? What am I doing wrong?

- I have a custom layout for the Item of the ListView
- The Activity is a simple one, not ListActivity
- In the ItemLayout I have 3 TextViews and perhaps an image.
- on Item Click I need to retrieve the value found in these TextViews.

So what might be my problem?
Here is the code:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                MainActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("ListView OnClick");
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
            TextView titlu = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
                    rl.findViewById(R.id.txtLocalitate);
            adb.setMessage("Selected = "+ titlu.getText().toString());
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            adb.show();
        }
    });
```

If I do

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) arg0.getParent();
```

then I do not receive an error on click, but the value displayed in the AlertDialog displays only the first item's value. So that's not the way to go...
If I leave the code as above, onItemClick I receive an error with "Force Close". The error log is available bellow:

```
07-30 18:36:09.903: W/dalvikvm(1304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ListView
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at softwarex.mycostomlistview.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:50)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-30 18:36:09.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
```

Assuming your list item is based on a `RelativeLayout`, then `v` *is* the RelativeLayout you're looking for, not its parent. Try this:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v;
```

*This assumes it really **is** a `RelativeLayout`. If you have mixed/varied list items, make sure you have some way of telling them apart, or you'll get another `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast your AdapterView (in this case I assume is a ListView) to a RelativeLayout so a ClassCastException is thrown. v is the view in which the click happened and it's the one you must use to get your TextView's. So instead of

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) v.getParent();
```

you should use

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v;
```